# Asynchronous Functions

Tags: concurrency, groovy, gpars

Is there a difference between [Asynchronous Invocation](http://www.gpars.org/1.0.0/guide/guide/dataParallelism.html#dataParallelism_asynchronousInvocation) and [Composable Asynchronous Functions](http://www.gpars.org/1.0.0/guide/guide/dataParallelism.html#dataParallelism_composableAsynchronousFunctions)?
In the first case you use `async()` or `callAsync()` and in the other case you use `asyncFun()`. But where is the main difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`asyncFun()` allows to compose asynchronous functions, while `async()` does not. asyncFun()-enhanced functions return Promises with all their bells and whistles, while async-enhanced functions return plain old `java.util.concurrent.Future`.

`async()` is a thin wrapper around Java's ExecutorServices. `asyncFun()` aims much higher and alters the whole signature of the function, including parameter types.

Comment: From the inventor himself! ;)